# ¿Cómo mostrar diálogo solo una vez en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, alertdialog, dialog

Al abrir mi aplicación siempre se muestra un diálogo que se cierra cuando presionas "Ok", me gustaría que solo se muestre la primera vez que abren la aplicación, este es mi código:

```
val miDialogo = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
miDialogo.setTitle(R.string.dialogo_titulo)
miDialogo.setMessage(R.string.dialogo_mensage)
miDialogo.setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
val dialog = miDialogo.create()
dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una Preferencia, para guardar un valor el cual indica ya me mostró el diálogo.

Realiza dos funciones, una para configurar el valor en la preferencia y otra para leerlo

```
fun setDialogValue(ctx: Context?, enabled: Int) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putInt("dialogo", enabled).apply()
}

fun getDialogValue(ctx: Context?): Int {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt("dialogo", 1)
}
```

De esta forma validarías mostrar el dialogo solo una vez:

```
 if(getDialogValue(applicationContext) == 1){

        showDialog() //Muestra el diálogo.

        setDialogValue(applicationContext, 0) //Desactivará mostrar dialogo

  }
```

---

- Si usas SharedPreferences en Kotlin, usa la dependencia:

  ```
   implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
  ```

Comment: Me funcionó, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

yo lo hice mas facil, inicializas una variable en la parte superior de tu codigo private var inicioUser =true y luego en tu dialogo  pones un if para preguntar si la condicion es igual a la de inicializacion, que solo se da al abrir el programa, dentro del if la cambias a false y listo. Asi te queda:   if (inicioUser==true) {
inicioUser=false